# Fast, portable, c++ math library for matrix and vector manipulations

Tags: math, matrix, vector

I have my own game engine which is written in opengl and c++. I also have my own math library for matrix and vectors manipulations. I always had doubts about the performance of my math library, so I recently decided to search for some popular math library which is used by many game / graphics developers. I was surprised that I couldn't find anything.

People on stackoverflow suggested GLM and Eigen libraries in similar posts, so I made some performance tests. I multiplied 1000000 times two matrices 4x4, and here are results:

```
GLM: 4.23 seconds
Eigen: 12.57 seconds
My library: 0.25 seconds
```

I was surprised by these results, because my implementation of multiplying matrices is taken from wikipedia. I checked the code from glm and eigen and I found, that there is a lot of typedefs, assertions and other type checking, unnecessary code, which decrease performance a lot.

So, my question is:
Do you know any FAST math library with nice API for gamedev / graphics purpose? I need functionality like: creating translation, rotation, projection, matrix * matrix, inverse, look at, matrix * vector, quaternions, etc...

Comment: Armadillo is an option.

Comment: Not really helpful, but anybody that needs one usually writes there own. Or it's just part of a larger framework like a game engine. It kind of makes sure that you know what you are doing :) I remember a Carmack saying that he starts every new project by writing new matrix and vector code.

Answer (score 2):

> I checked the code from glm and eigen and I found, that there is a lot of typedefs, assertions and other type checking, unnecessary code, which decrease performance a lot.

Are you sure that you have done all this benchmarks using higher compiler optimization ON ?

And not for example using Debug settings ?

Another alternative would be also MathFu from Google.
http://google.github.io/mathfu/